# Changing how a collection of citations is shown in Lyx

Tags: bibliographies, lyx

I am using Lyx to write a report. I import a .bib library to the report and then pick my desired sources from the list.
When I reference several sources at once, they look like this [3, 4, 5, 6] in the report. How do I change it to look like this: [3-6]?

Thanks!

Comment: How do you create your bibliography? Is it a BibTeX bibliography, or one you've written yourself in the document?

Comment: It's a BibTeX bibliography yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options:

1. **Natbib**

   Go to Document --> Settings --> Bibliography, choose *Natbib* as Citation style, and *Numerical* as Natbib style:

   [image: LyX document settings]
2. **The cite package**

   Go to Document --> Settings --> LaTeX preamble and add

   ```
   \usepackage{cite}
   ```